# How to install Nemerle with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nemerle

I have installed NemerleSetup-net.
This created a Nemerle folder in `c:\Program File(x86)\Nemerle`

but no extensions in `VS2012 Common7\IDE\Extensions` and so, I can't find any project template in the `IDE`

Could someone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: @CloseVote this question is **clearly** on-topic. It satisfies two of the four points here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 3):

Nemerle has support for VS 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013.
You can download the installer here: http://www.nemerle.org/Downloads .

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe Nemerle is integrated with Visual Studio 2012 yet. As far as I know only VS 2008 and VS 2010 are supported.

The source code for the Visual Studio integration is located [here](https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/tree/master/VsIntegration). It looks like no work has taken place on this for at least 10 months.

I think most people using Nemerle are using alternative text editors. I'm personally using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), which has a Nemerle syntax highlighting plugin and works great.